# How to modify DIY slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new at jquery and I found this DIY slider tutorial online and what I'm trying to do is modify it so when the first image is loaded the back button will hide, and when the last image is loaded the forward button will hide, and anything in between will show both buttons(forward and back). How can I go about doing this?

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/id_squared/bj4yZ/453/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "820px", // width of the slider
    height: "160px", // height of the slider
    display: 1, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false // disable looping on slides
}); // this is all you need!

// use buttons to change slide
$("#go-left").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "back");
});
$("#go-right").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle "moved.diyslider" event - it gives you current slide number. Knowing slide number you can show and hide buttons as desired:

```
$('#go-left').hide()

$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px", // width of the slider
    height: "200px", // height of the slider
    display: 1, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false // disable looping on slides
}).bind("moved.diyslider", function(event, slide, slideNumber){

    if (slideNumber > 1) 
        $('#go-left').show();    
    else
        $('#go-left').hide();    

    if (slideNumber < 5) 
        $('#go-right').show();    
    else
        $('#go-right').hide();    

})
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/456/**

Comment: Thank you, I studied all three of the examples, and I found this one to my liking, thank you, and thanks to everyone who helped me. I really learned a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this:

```
$(".slider").bind("moved.diyslider", function(event, slide, slideNumber, actuallyMoved){
    if ($("div.slider").find(".active").is(":first-child")) {
        $("#go-left").hide();
        $("#go-right").show();
    }else if ($("div.slider").find(".active").is(":last-child")) {
        $("#go-right").hide();
        $("#go-left").show();
    }else{
        $("#go-left").show();
        $("#go-right").show();
    }
});
```

This will work no matter how many slides you have.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a slide counter and hide and show the buttons when you are at the edges.

http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/455/

```
var currentSlide = 0
    maxSlides = $('.slider div div').length - 1;

$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px", // width of the slider
    height: "200px", // height of the slider
    display: 1, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false // disable looping on slides
}); // this is all you need!

$('#go-left').hide();
// use buttons to change slide
$("#go-left").bind("click", function(event, slide, slideNumber, actuallyMoved){
    currentSlide--;
    checkView();
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "back");
});
$("#go-right").bind("click", function(event, slide, slideNumber, actuallyMoved){
    currentSlide++;
    checkView();
   // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
});

var checkView = function() {
    if (currentSlide == 0) $('#go-left').hide();
    else $('#go-left').show();

    if (currentSlide == maxSlides) $('#go-right').hide();
    else $('#go-right').show();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  But, Yuriy's or James' answers are better.  The moved event is a nicer solution. :)